# Dependency injection has no value for non-static class and static method in c#

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a code downloaded from AWS for Signature Version 4. Their code goes like this:

```
public class PresignedUrl
{
     public static void Run(string a, string b, string c)
     {
     }
}
```

I want to apply dependency injection in order for me to use the configuration service which was registered as singleton. So it would turn out to be something like this:

```
using MyNamespace.Services.Interfaces;

public class PresignedUrl
{
     private static string _awsAccessKeyID;
     private static string _awsSecretKey;

     public PresignedUrl(IMyConfigurationService config)
     {
        _awsAccessKeyID = config.AWSAccessKeyID;
        _awsSecretKey = config.AWSSecretKey;
     }

     public static void Run(string a, string b, string c)
     {
     }
}
```

But the issue is there's no value inside `config.AWSAccessKeyID` and `config.AWSSecretKey`. But in other non-static method it has. When I debug it, the 2 mentioned variable are null.
How can I fixed it?

Comment: Can you post complete code. Especially the concrete implementation for IMyConfigurationService which you aim to inject

Comment: is `IMyConfigurationService config` resolved properly for the `PresignedUrl` ? `there's no value inside config.AWSAccessKeyID and config.AWSSecretKey. But in other non-static method it has` when it (config?) has value?

Comment: You have a `static` Run method, is `PresignedUrl` itself ever injected or otherwise instantiated?

Comment: Well, of course.  When the static method is called, the class is not instantiated, i.e. no object is created and nothing will be injected.  Try to make a static constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have non-static constructor for `PresignedUrl`, static fields `_awsAccessKeyID` and `_awsSecretKey` do not have values assigned until you run the code in the constructor.

When you create PresignedUrl class instance, you can access `_awsAccessKeyID` and `_awsSecretKey` from both static and non-static methods:

```cs
        PresignedUrl.Run("a", "b", "c");

        var config = new MyConfigurationService
        {
            AWSAccessKeyID = "id",
            AWSSecretKey = "key"
        };
        var instance = new PresignedUrl(config);

        PresignedUrl.Run("a", "b", "c");
        instance.NonStatiacRun("a", "b", "c");
```

Output:

```
_awsAccessKeyID: 
_awsSecretKey: 
_awsAccessKeyID: id
_awsSecretKey: key
_awsAccessKeyID: id
_awsSecretKey: key
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jz1hIB

Comment: Although what I did was removed the static signature in my methods and thus making the class insubstantiable but since I asked, this answer can be considered as the acceptable.